# ASP.NET MVC - How to import from excel and save to database with Foreign Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have these models:

**COUNTRIES**

```
public int COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
public string COUNTRY_NAME { get; set; }
```

**STATES**

```
public int STATE_ID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
public string STATE_NAME { get; set; }
```

**CITIES**

```
public int CITY_ID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> STATE_ID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> COUNTRY_ID { get; set; }
public string CITY_NAME { get; set; }
```

I already have data in COUNTRIES AND STATES. But I want to import into CITIES. While IMPORTING I want it to relate the COUNTRY_ID in CITIES TO COUNTRY_NAME in COUNTRIES, and also STATE_ID in CITIES with STATE_NAME in STATES. Whereby it will save the int and not string into CITIES.

The data in Excel are in strings

Import controller:

```
public ActionResult ImportCitiesExcel(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
{
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        var bodsList = new List<CITIES>();

        if (FileUpload != null)
        { 
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["FileUpload"];

            if (true)//FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" || FileUpload.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
            {
                string message = "";

                using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
                {
                    var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                    // if(currentSheet.Count)
                    var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                    var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                    var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;

                    for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                    {
                        var bod = new CITIES();
                        bod.CITY_ID = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Text;
                        bod.CITY_NAME = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Text;
                        bod.COUNTRY_ID = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Text;
                        bod.STATE_ID = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Text;
                        bodsList.Add(bod);
                    }
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                //alert message for invalid file format  
                data.Add("<ul>");
                data.Add("<li>Only Excel file format is allowed</li>");
                data.Add("</ul>");
                data.ToArray();
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            data.Add("<ul>");

            if (FileUpload == null) 
                data.Add("<li>Please choose Excel file</li>");

            data.Add("</ul>");
            data.ToArray();

            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

[Cities Excel sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbcZu.png)

But, when I export it should Display COUNTRY_NAME and not COUNTRY_ID, STATE_NAME and not STATE_ID

**Export Controller**

```
        public void CityToExcel()
    {
        IEnumerable<CITIES> cities = _cacService.GetCacs();
        ExcelPackage ePackage = new ExcelPackage();
        ExcelWorksheet eWorksheet = ePackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Reports");

        eWorksheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "Report";
        eWorksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "CITIES";

        eWorksheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "Date";
        eWorksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy} at {0:H: mm tt}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

        eWorksheet.Cells["A4"].Value = "CITY_NAME";
        eWorksheet.Cells["B4"].Value = "COUNTRY_NAME";
        eWorksheet.Cells["C4"].Value = "STATE_NAME";


        int rowStart = 5;
        foreach (var item in cities)
        {
            eWorksheet.Cells["A4:J4"].Style.Font.Bold = true;
            eWorksheet.Cells["A4:J4"].Style.Font.UnderLine = true;

            eWorksheet.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.CITY_NAME;
            eWorksheet.Cells[string.Format("B{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.COUNTRY_NAME;
            eWorksheet.Cells[string.Format("C{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.STATE_NAME;

            eWorksheet.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();
            rowStart++;
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment: filename=" + "CITIESReport.xlsx");
        Response.BinaryWrite(ePackage.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Please how do I go about it. Thanks